# Why mongoDB is taking more time to fetch as compare to mysql and how can I improve this MongoDB query

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

mysql table is like this

```
      longtitude latitude indexValue  color
       45.656     12.43    0.45        rgba(212,0,5,0.1)
       45.646     12.43    0.45        rgba(212,0,5,0.1)
```

similarly there is more than 6k data

mongoDB  1st collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58945d657e76045ef510d18f"),
"indexValue" : 0.293522894382477,
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        78.7457818889096, 
        20.6279312608142
    ]
},
"color" : "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)"
}
```

similarly there is more than 6k data

mongoDB 2st collection

```
enter code here
  {
"_id" : ObjectId("58906c5b8450b0c2e8bc2616"),
"longitude" : 78.7453240532948,
"latitude" : 20.6279312608142,
"indexValue" : 0.316524922847748,
"color" : "rgba(85,255,0,0.6)"
}
```

similarly there is more than 6k data

i fetching records from database using java 
mysql table takes only less than 2 seconds to fetch data and draw that polygon on map where as collection 1 takes more than 4 seconds to fetch and draw it on map and collection 2 takes more 7 seconds.

here is the code for fetching data from mysql table

```
                public String getGeoJsonData(BigDecimal log1, BigDecimal log2, BigDecimal lat1, BigDecimal lat2, BigDecimal km,int noofgeojson, String parentFilter, String childFilter, String date) {


    GeoJsonData geojson = null;
    int listCount = 0;
    String sql;
    String tableName = null;
    JSONObject parentObj = new JSONObject();





        parentObj.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

        JSONArray featuresArrayObj = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject featureObj = null;
        JSONObject geometryObj = null;
        JSONObject propertyObj = null;

        Connection con = gc.connectToDatabase();

        LOGGER.info("Results fetched");

        if (noofgeojson == 0)               
            sql = "select * from "+tableName.toLowerCase()+" where longitude > ? and longitude < ? and latitude > ? and latitude < ?";                      
        else
            sql = "select * from "+tableName.toLowerCase()+" where longitude > ? and longitude < ? and latitude > ? and latitude < ? limit "            
                    + noofgeojson;

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        System.out.println("SQL : " + sql);
        pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, log1);
        pstmt.setBigDecimal(2, log2);
        pstmt.setBigDecimal(3, lat1);
        pstmt.setBigDecimal(4, lat2);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        String sql1;

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "AFTER QUERY EXECUTION.. Records :: ");
        LOGGER.info("Results fetched");

        while (rs.next()) {
            featureObj = new JSONObject();  
            geometryObj = new JSONObject();
            propertyObj = new JSONObject();


            BigDecimal longitude = rs.getBigDecimal("longitude");
            BigDecimal latitude = rs.getBigDecimal("latitude");

            BigDecimal x1 = longitude.add(km);
            BigDecimal x2 = longitude.subtract(km);
            BigDecimal y1 = latitude.add(km);
            BigDecimal y2 = latitude.subtract(km);


            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point2 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point3 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point4 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point5 = new ArrayList<>();

            point1.add(x1);
            point1.add(y2);

            point2.add(x2);
            point2.add(y2);

            point3.add(x2);
            point3.add(y1);

            point4.add(x1);
            point4.add(y1);

            point5.add(x1);
            point5.add(y2);

            ArrayList<List<BigDecimal>> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

            coordinates.add(point1);
            coordinates.add(point2);
            coordinates.add(point3);
            coordinates.add(point4);
            coordinates.add(point5);

            ArrayList<List<List<BigDecimal>>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

            finalList.add(coordinates);

            geometryObj.put("coordinates",finalList);
            geometryObj.put("type","Polygon");

            featureObj.put("geometry", geometryObj);
            featureObj.put("type", "Feature");

            propertyObj.put("description", parentFilter+" : "+rs.getBigDecimal("indexValue"));
            propertyObj.put("color", rs.getString("color"));
            propertyObj.put("indexValue", rs.getBigDecimal("indexValue"));

            featureObj.put("properties", propertyObj);

            featuresArrayObj.put(featureObj);
        }

        parentObj.put("features", featuresArrayObj);
        System.out.println("Done");
        System.gc();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    finally {
        System.out.println("GeoJson List Count :: " + listCount);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    return parentObj.toString();
}
```

here is the code for 1st Collection

```
          public String getGeoJsonData_geo(String tablename, BigDecimal log1, BigDecimal log2, BigDecimal lat1, BigDecimal lat2,
        BigDecimal km, int noofgeojson, String parentFilter, String childFilter, String date) throws UnknownHostException {
    double LOG1 = log1.doubleValue();
    double LOG2 = log2.doubleValue();
    double LAT1 = lat1.doubleValue();
    double LAT2 = lat2.doubleValue();
    System.out.println("LOG1 "+LOG1);
    System.out.println("LOG2 "+LOG2);
    System.out.println("LAT1 "+LAT1);
    System.out.println("LAT2 "+LAT2);
    System.out.println("In c.m.u.CSCDBUtil.getGeoJsonData");

      System.out.println("noofgeojson :: " + noofgeojson);

      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
      DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "hdfccrop" );

    GeoJsonData geojson = null;
    int listCount = 0;
    String sql;
    String tableName = tablename;
    JSONObject parentObj = new JSONObject();

        parentObj.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

        JSONArray featuresArrayObj = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject featureObj = null;
        JSONObject geometryObj = null;
        JSONObject propertyObj = null;

        Connection con = gc.connectToDatabase();

        LOGGER.info("Results fetched");
          DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(tablename);
             LOGGER.info("Collection mycol selected successfully");
             List<BasicDBObject> criteria=new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
             List<BasicDBList> outputs = new ArrayList<BasicDBList>();  
             List box=new ArrayList();

        if (noofgeojson == 0)               

        {
                 box.add(new double[]{78.73588012695312,20.61859024115912});
                 box.add(new double[]{78.76874400138855,20.638818134959076});           
        }
            else
            {

            }

         BasicDBObject querybox = new BasicDBObject("location", new BasicDBObject("$within",
                 new BasicDBObject("$box", box)));
         DBObject loc;
         BasicDBList coords;
         BigDecimal latitude;
         BigDecimal longitude;
         BigDecimal x1;
         BigDecimal x2;
         BigDecimal y1;
         BigDecimal y2;
         ArrayList<BigDecimal> point1;
         ArrayList<BigDecimal> point2;
         ArrayList<BigDecimal> point3;
         ArrayList<BigDecimal> point4;
         ArrayList<BigDecimal> point5 ;
         ArrayList<List<BigDecimal>> coordinates;
         ArrayList<List<List<BigDecimal>>> finalList;

             DBCursor cursor = coll.find(querybox); 

             DBObject cursorObj;
             while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
                     cursorObj = cursor.next();




                 featureObj = new JSONObject(); 
                    geometryObj = new JSONObject();
                    propertyObj = new JSONObject();



                    loc =(DBObject) cursorObj.get("location");
                    coords= (BasicDBList) loc.get("coordinates");

                    Object temp1=coords.get(1);

                     latitude = new BigDecimal(temp1.toString());



                    Object temp2=coords.get(0);
                     longitude = new BigDecimal(temp2.toString());

                     LOGGER.info("done getting ");  

             x1 = longitude.add(km);

             x2 = longitude.subtract(km);

             y1 = latitude.add(km);

             y2 = latitude.subtract(km);


             point1 = new ArrayList<>();
                 point2 = new ArrayList<>();
                 point3 = new ArrayList<>();
                 point4 = new ArrayList<>();
                 point5 = new ArrayList<>();
                 coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
                 finalList = new ArrayList<>();

            point1.add(x1);
            point1.add(y2);

            point2.add(x2);
            point2.add(y2);

            point3.add(x2);
            point3.add(y1);

            point4.add(x1);
            point4.add(y1);

            point5.add(x1);
            point5.add(y2);



            coordinates.add(point1);
            coordinates.add(point2);
            coordinates.add(point3);
            coordinates.add(point4);
            coordinates.add(point5);




            finalList.add(coordinates);

            geometryObj.put("coordinates",finalList);
            geometryObj.put("type","Polygon");

            featureObj.put("geometry", geometryObj);
            featureObj.put("type", "Feature");
            propertyObj.put("description", parentFilter+" : "+cursorObj.get("indexValue"));
            propertyObj.put("color",cursorObj.get("color") );

            propertyObj.put("indexValue", cursorObj.get("indexValue"));

            featureObj.put("properties", propertyObj);
            featuresArrayObj.put(featureObj);

        }

        parentObj.put("features", featuresArrayObj);

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.gc();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    finally {
        System.out.println("GeoJson List Count :: " + listCount);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

        return parentObj.toString();


}
```

Here is code for 2nd collection

```
         public String getGeoJsonData_Demo(String tablename, BigDecimal log1, BigDecimal log2, BigDecimal lat1, BigDecimal lat2,
        BigDecimal km, int noofgeojson, String parentFilter, String childFilter, String date) throws UnknownHostException {
    double LOG1 = log1.doubleValue();
    double LOG2 = log2.doubleValue();
    double LAT1 = lat1.doubleValue();
    double LAT2 = lat2.doubleValue();
    System.out.println("LOG1 "+LOG1);
    System.out.println("LOG2 "+LOG2);
    System.out.println("LAT1 "+LAT1);
    System.out.println("LAT2 "+LAT2);
    System.out.println("In c.m.u.CSCDBUtil.getGeoJsonData");

      System.out.println("noofgeojson :: " + noofgeojson);

      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
      DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "hdfccrop" );

    GeoJsonData geojson = null;
    int listCount = 0;
    String sql;
    String tableName = tablename;
    JSONObject parentObj = new JSONObject();


        parentObj.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

        JSONArray featuresArrayObj = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject featureObj = null;
        JSONObject geometryObj = null;
        JSONObject propertyObj = null;

        Connection con = gc.connectToDatabase();

        LOGGER.info("Results fetched");
          DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(tablename);
             LOGGER.info("Collection mycol selected successfully");
             List<BasicDBObject> criteria=new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
        if (noofgeojson == 0)               

        {


                 BasicDBObject searchQuery1 =new BasicDBObject("longitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", LOG1).append("$lte",  LOG2));
                 criteria.add(searchQuery1);
                 BasicDBObject searchQuery2=new BasicDBObject("latitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", LAT1).append("$lte",  LAT2));
                 criteria.add(searchQuery2); 
                 LOGGER.info("Collection mycol selected ");


        }
            else


            {

            }



        BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("$and",criteria);
             DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query); 

             while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
                    DBObject cursorObj = cursor.next();

                 featureObj = new JSONObject(); 
                    geometryObj = new JSONObject();
                    propertyObj = new JSONObject();


                    Object temp1 = cursorObj.get("latitude");
                    BigDecimal latitude = new BigDecimal(temp1.toString());
                    System.out.println("Longitude is "+latitude);
                    Object temp2 =cursorObj.get("longitude");
                    BigDecimal longitude = new BigDecimal(temp2.toString());
                    System.out.println("Latitude is "+longitude);
                     LOGGER.info("done getting ");  

            BigDecimal x1 = longitude.add(km);
            System.out.println("x1 is"+x1);
            BigDecimal x2 = longitude.subtract(km);
            System.out.println("x2 is "+x2);
            BigDecimal y1 = latitude.add(km);
            System.out.println("y1 is "+y1);
            BigDecimal y2 = latitude.subtract(km);
            System.out.println("y2 is "+y2);

            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point2 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point3 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point4 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> point5 = new ArrayList<>();

            point1.add(x1);
            point1.add(y2);

            point2.add(x2);
            point2.add(y2);

            point3.add(x2);
            point3.add(y1);

            point4.add(x1);
            point4.add(y1);

            point5.add(x1);
            point5.add(y2);

            ArrayList<List<BigDecimal>> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

            coordinates.add(point1);
            coordinates.add(point2);
            coordinates.add(point3);
            coordinates.add(point4);
            coordinates.add(point5);

            ArrayList<List<List<BigDecimal>>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();


            finalList.add(coordinates);

            geometryObj.put("coordinates",finalList);
            geometryObj.put("type","Polygon");

            featureObj.put("geometry", geometryObj);
            featureObj.put("type", "Feature");
            propertyObj.put("description", parentFilter+" : "+cursorObj.get("indexValue"));
            propertyObj.put("color",cursorObj.get("color") );

            propertyObj.put("indexValue", cursorObj.get("indexValue"));

            featureObj.put("properties", propertyObj);
            featuresArrayObj.put(featureObj);

        }


        parentObj.put("features", featuresArrayObj);

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.gc();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    finally {
        System.out.println("GeoJson List Count :: " + listCount);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }


        return parentObj.toString();


}
```

i have apply indexing in first collection like this

```
       db.collection.createIndex( { "location.coordinates": "2d" } )
```

but there was no change

indexing for seconds collection was simple indexing on longitude and latitude but there was improvement of 2seconds ......

does anybody know why this is happing since i think mongoDB is faster for fetching the records as compare to mysql but here there is a big difference max time taken by mysql was 2 seconds where collection 1 takes 4 seconds and collection 2 takes 7 to 8 seconds

is there any problem in my java code !!!!

I'm fetching all records from table and collections

Comment: have you created index on the mongo collection?

Comment: yes i have used    db.collection.createIndex( { "location.coordinates": "2d" } ) for collection one

Comment: It's hard to work out what you are comparing given your code has a lot of conditional parameters that may be added to the queries. I would start by focusing on a single MongoDB query and the detailed [explain results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for that query. When asking questions it is also important to mention the specific version of MongoDB server you are using. It looks like you want to combine geo search with non-geospatial criteria: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#create-a-compound-index-with-2dsphere-index-key.

Comment: @Stennie i have fired query on terminal .. i have reviced very fast result...so i think there is somthing wrong in my java code which is causing extra time ....

Comment: Without any further details such as the actual query you are running, the explain output, and the version of MongoDB server it's impossible to know if the query could be improved with indexing. It does look like your MySQL code uses range queries while your first MongoDB approach uses the (deprecated) geospatial `$within` operator, so these are doing different amounts of calculation on the server. I suggest you edit this question down to a more specific "how can I improve this MongoDB query" with relevant details.

Comment: If you are measuring time for an end result (i.e. drawing a polygon on a map), you need to separately profile the time spent on the query vs the application code vs the UI rendering. Measurements also have to be considered over a number of iterations and you should monitor resources that might be limiting factors (i.e. RAM, CPU, I/O, network, ...).

Comment: @Stennie version of mongoDB is  v3.2.11... as i said fetching time from terminal is fast same as mysql but i think there is problem in my java code for mongoDB ..and m using  MongoClient for fecting from collection

Comment: query  for collection 1        box.add(new double[]{78.73588012695312,20.61859024115912});
                 box.add(new double[]{78.76874400138855,20.638818134959076});                          BasicDBObject querybox = new BasicDBObject("location", new BasicDBObject("$within",
                 new BasicDBObject("$box", box)));

Comment: query for collection 2                          BasicDBObject searchQuery1 =new BasicDBObject("longitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", LOG1).append("$lte",  LOG2));
                 criteria.add(searchQuery1);
                 BasicDBObject searchQuery2=new BasicDBObject("latitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", LAT1).append("$lte",  LAT2));
                 criteria.add(searchQuery2);                 BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("$and",criteria);